# INSERT INTO statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to enter information into my table named Food_Log.

```
INSERT INTO Food_Log
(Person, Food, ServingSize, Date, Meal);
VALUES
(John,'Cheerios',2,'1-APR-2014','Breakfast');
```

I am getting the following error because of this entry.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Not sure what to do in order to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `;` before `VALUES`

```
INSERT INTO Food_Log (Person, Food, ServingSize, Date, Meal)
VALUES ('John','Cheerios',2,'2014-04-01','Breakfast');
```

And date format is normally `YYYY-MM-DD`. And you forgot the quotes around `John`