# I have an incorrect syntax error

Tags: sql-server

```
INSERT INTO FoodLog
(Person,Food,ServingSize,Date,Meal)
VALUES
('John','Cheerios',2,'1-APR-2014','Breakfast')
('John','TBoneSteak',1,'2-APR-2014','Lunch')
```

In this code, the first line of code works just fine, but when I type up the second line of code with the same person name, it doesn't accept it.

This is the error that I receive:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near 'John'.

Comment: You are missing a comma in between the lines.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @helderdarocha answer is correct

Comment: Seems like this one answered your question. Please mark it as answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23164151/insert-into-statement-in-sql-server

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of having an answer rather than a comment. Exactly as @helderdarocha said, "You are missing a comma in between the lines."

```
INSERT INTO FoodLog (Person,Food,ServingSize,Date,Meal)
VALUES ('John','Cheerios',2,'1-APR-2014','Breakfast')
      ,('John','TBoneSteak',1,'2-APR-2014','Lunch')
```

Answer (score 2):

As @helderdarocha and @Karl Kieninger said you are missing a comma between the tuples 
or if you still cant resolve the issue, try writing individual entries....I can`t think of anything else possible...

```
    INSERT INTO FoodLog VALUES ('John','Cheerios',2,'1-APR-2014','Breakfast');
    INSERT INTO FoodLog VALUES ('John','TBoneSteak',1,'2-APR-2014','Lunch');
```